# How to set ML Flow to log test metrics in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, mlflow

I have set up ML Flow and the UI is logging the training metrics, but not the test metrics in sklearn. I am using Jupyter Notebooks and ML Flow UI

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can log any metric in the same way using:
`mlflow.log_metric()`.
For example:

```bash
mlflow.log_metric("val_acc", value, step)
```